# while loop inside an array

Tags: php, mysql

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE status='confirm' ORDER BY datetime DESC ");
$invoice = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
```

How do I echo mysql fetch data like as following:

```
$data = array(
array("firstname" => "Mary", "lastname" => "Johnson", "age" => 25),
array("firstname" => "Amanda", "lastname" => "Miller", "age" => 18),
array("firstname" => "James", "lastname" => "Brown", "age" => 31),
array("firstname" => "Patricia", "lastname" => "Williams", "age" => 7),
array("firstname" => "Michael", "lastname" => "Davis", "age" => 43),
array("firstname" => "Sarah", "lastname" => "Miller", "age" => 24),
array("firstname" => "Patrick", "lastname" => "Miller", "age" => 27)
);
```

Comment: Just append a new subArray to it?! `$data[] = ["xy" => "xy"];`. Not sure if I understand your question right.

Comment: I don't get it, **Please explain** and excuse my ignorance.

Comment: [How to ask good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to iterate through the results and add the values to your data array:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE status='confirm' ORDER BY datetime DESC ");
$data = array();
while ($invoice = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
  $data[] = array(
    'firstname' => $invoice['firstname'],
    'lastname' => $invoice['lastname'],
    'age' => $invoice['age'],
  );
}
```

`mysql_fetch_assoc($query)` returns only one row, so as long as it returns a result row (`while`), the loop is running and adds the values to the `$data` array.

Comment: You should *explain* your answer.

Comment: Just give me a second. ;)

Comment: Come up with the explanation before hitting "submit" next time

Comment: @Paul
Thanks a lot

Comment: Looping this way after a query is wrong and bad practice.  You have to SELECT the proper fileds in your query instead of using *. The query result is your array. No loop needed.